# How to use the same source for two paths - Angular 9

Tags: angular, routes

Can I use the same source like this ?

```
  {path: 'experiences/:id', component: DetailsExperienceComponent},
  {path: 'experiences/create', component: FormExperienceComponent, canActivate: [AuthService]},
  {path: '**', component: NotFountComponent},
```

In my case, the second path is redirected to NotFoundComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the second route first. The routes are evaluated in the order they appear:

```js
...
{path: 'experiences/create', component: FormExperienceComponent, canActivate: [AuthService]},
{path: 'experiences/:id', component: DetailsExperienceComponent},
...
```

By doing so, `experiences/:id` will be evaluated only if `experiences/create` doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

try this using Componentless Routes:

```
{
    path: 'experiences',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'create',
            component: FormExperienceComponent, canActivate: [AuthService]
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: DetailsExperienceComponent
        } 
    ]    
},
{path: '**', component: NotFountComponent}
```

Comment: thank you but the order is important as @julianobrasil said. grateful for your response